# Play music files from Phone's directory

Tags: flutter, local-storage, audio-player, flutter-audioplayers

I am developing an application where users can download songs and play them offline. These downloaded songs will remain within the app. I implement the download feature using [flutter_downloader: ^1.10.2](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader). Now I want to play that downloaded music in the app using [audioplayers: ^3.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers). How to load music from device storage in flutter?

```
  final player = AudioPlayer();

await player.play(DeviceFileSource(
                              'data/user/0/{appName}/app_flutter/{fileName}')
```

This code throws the error -
Unexpected error!
D/AudioPlayers(12795): java.io.FileNotFoundException: "myFilePath data/user/0/{appName}/app_flutter/{fileName} ": open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: seems like your path is incorrect, replace {appName} and {fileName} with proper path values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution for that, Maybe extension was the issue
*Process to save file*

```
final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
var localPath = dir.path + name; //Name : Folder name

await dio.download({content URL},"$localPath/${YourFileName}.$extension",
       onReceiveProgress: (receivedBytes, totalBytes) {
     downloadPercentage.value = ((receivedBytes / totalBytes));
     //Further stuff
   });
```

Path will be - "$localPath/${YourFileName}.$extension"

Process to fetch file

```
await player.play(DeviceFileSource(
                              '$localPath/${YourFileName}.$extension')
```